# .vim syntax highlighting to textmate or sublime text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, textmate

I have a `.vim script` for highlighting a specific program's syntax (Mplus SEM software).

I am wondering if there is an easy way to convert this to textmate or sublime text 2
or do I need to write my own.

Best and thanks in advance.

[Vim script](http://www.unc.edu/~jmroos/micah/OddsEnds_files/mplus.vim)

Note: I did not write this script, but would like to thank J Micah Roos.

**EDIT:**

Not really an answer, but I gave up trying to find a way and made my own package to do what I wanted:
https://github.com/bkeller2/Mplus

Just putting it there for anyone who comes across this needing this syntax highlighter.

Comment: Nope no easy way (that I know of) to do it. That being said, if you do write a script to help convert vim syntax files to sublime text, I know there are others who would find that useful. http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=8698

Comment: @user2316204 What tools/how did you end up building the .tmTheme yourself? I'm trying to do this myself for a different language

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use vim syntax definition with sublime-text2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687815/use-vim-syntax-definition-with-sublime-text2)