# Converting Emacs/vim highlighting to TextMate (for SublimeText)

Tags: vim, emacs, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext3, textmate

I have syntax highlighting [files](https://github.com/brownplt/pyret-lang/tree/master/tools) for Pyret in vim (.vim) and emacs (.el) and would like to use them in Sublime Text (3).

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15236992/4283301) and other research, Sublime Text style themes are written in [TextMate format](http://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars).

There exists [a tool](https://github.com/emacsfodder/tmtheme-to-emacs) to help convert from TextMate to Emacs, but I contacted the author and he isn't aware of any tools to help facilitate the opposite conversion.

A similar question was asked (re: vim) but not answered a year ago: [.vim syntax highlighting to textmate or sublime text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195947/vim-syntax-highlighting-to-textmate-or-sublime-text-2) -- that asker ended up building [his own TextMate theme](https://github.com/bkeller2/Mplus) manually, but I'm not sure how to go about that.

I would like to know if there have been developed any tools to help convert a vim or emacs syntax style file to TextMate, and, if not, how I would go about converting the vim/el [files](https://github.com/brownplt/pyret-lang/tree/master/tools) into JSON/XML for importing into TextMate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I haven't been able to find any tools to help me out, I have found some help.

[This explanation](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_your_own_syntax_files) of how to build a vim style guide has proven invaluable in helping me understand the construction of the vim syntax file I am converting.

This [a super-helpful guide](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html) is walking me through how to manually build a template in YAML and then convert it to SublimeText's tmLanguage via the PackageDev SublimeText package.

**EDIT**: My solution, with instructions, is available [here](https://github.com/brownplt/pyret-lang/tree/master/tools/sublime).