# pasm syntax highlighting in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, beagleboneblack

I'm programming the Beaglebone Black's "Programmable Real-Time Unit" in an assembly language called [pasm](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/PRU_Assembly_Instructions). I would like Sublime Text to color my code (syntax highlight).

Texas Instruments provides pasm language definition files for Vim, Notepad++, and TextPad:

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/PASM_Syntax_Highlighting

Is there some way to use one of these in Sublime Text 3?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592093/converting-emacs-vim-highlighting-to-textmate-for-sublimetext) link describes the syntax-highlighting method for ST2, but in ST3 they've changed it to use `.sublime-syntax` files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Emacs/vim highlighting to TextMate (for SublimeText)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592093/converting-emacs-vim-highlighting-to-textmate-for-sublimetext)

Comment: @Keith, that post helps, but ST3 they've updated how their syntax highlighting works.

Comment: I created my own .sublime-syntax file for pasm [here](https://github.com/justinpearson/pasm-sublime-text-syntax-highlight).